# Typescript errors in d.ts files --> can't combine files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

I installed the angular2 `definitlytyped-libraries` via `nuget` in my project (VS2015).
The problem that I'm facing now is that there are multiple versioned files

- angular2-2.0.0-alpha.26.d.ts
- angular2-2.0.0-alpha.28.d.ts
- angular2-2.0.0-alpha.30.d.ts
- angular2-2.0.0-alpha.31.d.ts
- angular2-2.0.0-alpha.32.d.ts

while building my project (to combine all my ts-files to one single js-file - I'm using the build-in combine-functionality) I'm getting over 2000 errors like `"Duplicate identifier ..."`

how can I handle this errors and bundle my project?

Comment: Delete unneeded ones? You only need `angular2.d.ts`. It is identical to `angular2-2.0.0-alpha.32.d.ts`. I`m not sure why they keep the old ones around.

Comment: ok that was easy.But why is it installing this previous anyway? If I need a previous version I should just install this...anyway it worked. thanks!

Comment: Ah nuget. I would recommend [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd). Using `tsd install angular2` should install the correct version.

Comment: ok that looks much nicer now :) can you also provide me a command line how to get the angular2-router and angular2/http ?

Comment: `tsd install router` should do it. `http` type definitions are in `angular2.d.ts`.